# Bootstrap header but using px not aligning right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the header equal width its meant to be like the graphic below but its not turning out like that.

It should look like the following[image] This is just for my own learning from a random psd on the web. Also would my code be acurate is it right to use px should I be using percentages also I should be using bootstrap more with the likes of a header.

This is what is looks like with the code below

[image]

css used style.css

```
.header-text
{

    font-size:30pt
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
     width: 220px;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top:54;
     text-align: center;
    float:left;
}

.header
{
    height:240px;
 }
div>div.header-logo
{
    background-image: url("logo.png");
    width: 240x;
    height: 270px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

div>div.expert-reviews
{
    float:left;
      font-size:30pt
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body > div > div:nth-child(3)
{
    float:right;
      font-size:30pt
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-text">100+ Years Of Combiend Industry Expierence</div>

                               <div class="header-logo"></div>    
        <div class"expert-reviews"> Expert Consumer Reviews and Ratings</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of modifying your own html with `float`, I would suggest you use bootstrap grid system.
[Bootstrap Grid System Basic](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) , 
[Bootstrap Grid System Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

Comment: And if you can, use bootstrap 4.1. The new grid system is using flex and that header setup will be trivial.